# calling listactiviy from tabactivity in android

Tags: android, listactivity, tabactivity

Is it possible to call listactivity through tab activity? Basically, I am developing an app with 3 tabs, for which I am using tabactivity. Furthermore, in one of the tabs I want a listview, so I have derived from listactivity.

Now I want the click event to be determined in the listview. Am i missing something?

```
public class Tabissue extends TabActivity 
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TabHost host    =   getTabHost();

    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab1").setContent(new Intent(this,Tab1.class)));
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Tab2").setContent(new Intent(this,Tab2.class)));
    host.setCurrentTab(1);
}
}
```

Tab1 Class

```
public class Tab2 extends ListActivity
   {
  ListView list;
  @Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.tab2);    

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Test1","####");
    map.put("Test2", "India");
    map.put("Time", "India time");
    mylist.add(map);
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Test1", "####");
    map.put("Test2", "US");
    map.put("Time","US time");
    mylist.add(map);
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Test1", "####");
    map.put("Test2", "UK");
    map.put("Time", "UK Time");
    mylist.add(map);

    ListAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(  this,
            mylist, 
            R.layout.row,
            new String[] 
            {
                "India", 
                "US", 
                "UK"
            }, 
            new int[] 
            {
                R.id.TRAIN_CELL, 
                R.id.FROM_CELL, 
                R.id.TO_CELL,
            }
        );
    list.setAdapter(mSchedule);    


}
```

}

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the exact problem you are facing? Right now I do not see any issue. Using a ListActivity as a tab should work out of the box.

Comment: @tg,
I have attached mine code for the app, which consists of 2 tabs, and a listview

Comment: What is the problem? Can't you set a click listener or the ListView doesn't appear at all?

Comment: My issue, i am unable to determine the click event.
I am once again repeating the scenario.

I have 2 tabs on my application , one tab consists of listview.
I have data populated on listview. 
When i click on aparticular row i want the click event of the listview to be fired.

Answer (score 2):

In your ListActivity set onItemClickListener:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                // Do your stuff here
            }
});
```