# Start ListActivity using ListActivity from a TabActivity?

Tags: android, sdk

I have a class extended by TabActivity that creates multiple tabs.
One tab is extended by ListActivity and should open a new activity when you choose an option in the list. The problem is that this code will lose the tabs (opening a new activity in the ListActivity that is member of the TabActivity):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MyOtherActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Is there a solution to this?
Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: As per MisterSquonk comment, I may have misunderstood the issue. I do not believe you can easily change the activity in that particular tab, but you have two equally feasible options:

- remove the tab with the `ListView` and add a new tab with the new `Activity`
  Add a new tab with:

  - `public void addTab (TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec)`
  - You can remove a single tab following the response here: [How to remove tab from TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299845/how-to-remove-tab-from-tabhost)
- Use a regular `Activity` instead and add a `FrameLayout` with the `ListView` and your alternative content inside:

  - use `bringToFront ()` to determine the `View` z order
  - use `setVisibility()` to either VISIBLE or GONE

---

Old, probably irrelevant info:

There are a couple of questions here dealing with similar setups:

[ListActivity inside TabActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116837/listactivity-inside-tabactivity)

[calling listactiviy from tabactivity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287606/calling-listactiviy-from-tabactivity-in-android)

and even a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3443

You can take a look at how they implemented it. My $0.02, just extend `Activity` instead and add a `ListView` inside.

Comment: I may be wrong but as far as I can tell, the OP wants to simply 'switch' the tab content (in one particular tab) from one Activity to another Activity rather than launch a new Activity which 'covers' the TabActivity. It's not specifically a ListActivity issue it's a general Activity as a tab content -> switch to any other Activity as a tab content issue.

Comment: @MisterSquonk you're probably right. Added two options to address that issue.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite see where I am supposed to put the code for adding a new tab and deleting the old one? Thanks for answering!

Comment: It would be good if I could access the TabHost from my ListActivity classes, is there a possibility? I have to reach the TabHost in my TabActivity class, right?

Comment: @dataviruset simply use `getParent()` from your `ListActivity`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getParent%28%29 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945274/android-tabhost-update-tabs-from-tabs-activity/2945675#2945675

Answer (score 0):

It would be an easier solution, if you would have the liberty to change a bit your design, and instead of the `ListActivity` you would have an activity with a custom layout rooted by a `ViewFlipper`. Inside this `ViewFlipper` you could set the first 'page' to your `ListView`, and the second page to the child activity's view.
On item click you just call `showNext` on the viewflipper, and populate the second layout with the proper data based on the selected item.